# Monero payment processing & confirmation in PHP

Tags: monerod, linux, payment-integration, php

I would like to create a payment gateway for the Monero crypto currency on my website. As practise, I don't want to use a third party payment processor. I was thinking JSON RPC calls would be a good idea. But I am not sure where to go from there.

The user must select an item for their cart, the cart must then be checked out with all the items. A payment address can be generated for each transaction (not sure if best way) and the script will check the transaction confirmations every time the user reloads the page.

I'm not sure where to go from here implementation wise, do I start a daemon full node and call JSON RPC endpoints to create the wallets or do I do it some other way/directly in the code.

- Do I make every address a sub address of a main marketplace wallet or do I make an entirely new unrelated wallet for every transaction?
- What libraries/RPC Methods might help me out?
- Any public implementations I can read for inspiration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> do I start a daemon full node and call JSON RPC endpoints to create the wallets or do I do it some other way/directly in the code.

You will almost certainly want to run a daemon and wallet. These expose the official JSON RPC methods to interact with the network and wallet. Pretty much every third party library just wraps these, so even if you use such a library you'll still need a daemon / wallet running anyway.

> Do I make every address a sub address of a main marketplace wallet or do I make an entirely new unrelated wallet for every transaction?

Based on the limited information provided, you'll likely want to use a subaddress per customer.

> What libraries/RPC Methods might help me out?

https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/, more specifically the [Daemon RPC](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html) and [Wallet RPC](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html).